# How to extract all contents from a Zip file using VB?

Tags: vb.net, unzip

I've found several examples online that work on something similar to my question (most eventually point to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The issue is, unless I'm misreading the code on the MSDN, their code only extracts one file from the zip.

I'm looking to do the equivalent of right clicking a .zip and saying extract to [insert folder path] and just have all the contents (files & folders) dumped into the folder I provide.

So I need to know:

1) Is this possible without a third party library?

2) If it is possible, how would I go about doing this? Do I have to loop through the files/folders in the zip and extract each individually? If a loop is needed, how to I point the loop at the file list in the zip?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using .Net Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .NET 4,  No. In .NET 4.5 it is possible by [ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx), or 3rd party, not hard to use them.

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't be able to DL or install due to my companies user settings :\ Thanks for the straight answer though, it's what I expected it was, but just wanted the confirmation.